# Creating a trigger that pulls information from another table in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am trying to create a fairly complicated Trigger and I'm not sure if it can be done on phpMyAdmin.

Right now I have this query that creates a table with all the information I need from it.

```
CREATE TABLE SeniorDB_Shipping

SELECT

    SeniorDB_Invoice.ID_Order, 
    SeniorDB_Customer.MCT_Code,
    SeniorDB_Customer.Customer_Name,
    SeniorDB_Customer.Customer_Address,
    SeniorDB_Customer.Customer_City,
    SeniorDB_Customer.Customer_State,
    SeniorDB_Invoice.Shipping_Company

FROM SeniorDB_Customer

Join SeniorDB_Invoice ON SeniorDB_Customer.MCT_Code = SeniorDB_Invoice.MCT_Code
```

[image: Inserted into this table]

As you can see in the image, when I run the query, it pulls in information from the tables above the information. I'm trying (and failing) to create a trigger that will do this same thing without having to `create` a brand new table every single time. All the other posts I have seen are similar in regards to `creating` a table instead of `inserting` to a table.

What the trigger does is, when I enter the `ID_Order`, the rest of the information will get pulled from the database.

This is the trigger I have so far:

```
    delimiter ~

        create trigger SeniorDB_Shipping before insert on SeniorDB_Shipping
        for each row begin
            set new.SeniorDB_Shipping.MCT_Code =            new.SeniorDB_Customer.MCT_Code,;
            set new.SeniorDB_Shipping.Customer_Name =       new.SeniorDB_Customer.Customer_Name,;
            set new.SeniorDB_Shipping.Customer_Address =    new.SeniorDB_Customer.Customer_Address,;
            set new.SeniorDB_Shipping.Customer_City =       new.SeniorDB_Customer.Customer_City,;
            set new.SeniorDB_Shipping.Customer_State =      new.SeniorDB_Customer.Customer_State,;
            set new.SeniorDB_Shipping.Shipping_Company =    new.SeniorDB_Customer.Shipping_Company,;
        end~

    delimiter ;
```

I feel like I'm right there. I just can't link it to when I enter the `ID_Order`.

This is the page if you would like to see the databases: http://polonium.forest.usf.edu/~sngamwon/SeniorProject/SeniorDB_Order.php

Comment: To clarify, the first query doesn't create a table, and you want a new table every time? If so, is there any reason for the new table?

Comment: My apologies, I changed it. I tried it earlier as `INSERT` but I received a lot of errors. It works as a `CREATE TABLE` but not as an `INSERT`. I'm assuming my syntax or understanding is a bit off

Comment: I can give you the correct query to run the insert into the same table you've pre-created. I don't think you need the trigger at all. Is that what you're after?

Comment: If it works, that would be perfect. I just assumed I needed a `trigger` since every time I try to run that first query as an `INSERT`, I get errors relating to `primary keys` and it duplicates the data instead of adding on to the table. That was another issue I found - it kept duplicating the data from `ID` = 1 through10 instead of starting at (for example) 5 through 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you'll need to run this once:

```
/* Create the table with a primary key */
create table `SeniorDB_Shipping` (
    `id` INT unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    primary key(id),
    `ID_Order` int NOT NULL,
    `MCT_Code` int NOT NULL,
    `Customer_Name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Customer_Address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Customer_City` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Customer_State` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `Shipping_Company` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Then you can run

```
/* Insert statement */
INSERT INTO `SeniorDB_Shipping` (
    `ID_Order`, 
    `MCT_Code`, 
    `Customer_Name`, 
    `Customer_Address`, 
    `Customer_City`,
    `Customer_State`,
    `Shipping_Company`
) SELECT
    invoice.ID_Order, 
    customer.MCT_Code,
    customer.Customer_Name,
    customer.Customer_Address,
    customer.Customer_City,
    customer.Customer_State,
    invoice.Shipping_Company
FROM 
    SeniorDB_Customer as customer
    Join SeniorDB_Invoice as invoice
        ON customer.MCT_Code = invoice.MCT_Code;
```

I've run this in my own PHPMyAdmin, so it works. But I obviously don't have your schema. Known issues:

- This will populate SeniorDB_Shipping with **ALL** the data from your two tables each time. Modify the query as required to select only recent data if that's not what you want. If ID_Order is a primary key you could check that doesn't already exist.

Comment: I'm not sure how to test this. Am I just supposed to enter an ID_Order number and it pulls the rest of the information?

Comment: It should create a new `SeniorDB_Shipping` table that you can view in PHPMyAdmin. Once you run the second query it'll add a row to that table for each row in `SeniorDB_Customer`. You can view `SeniorDB_Shipping` and make sure it has what you want. If later you want to load a single new row into that table from the other two tables run the same statement (second query) but add `where invoice.ID_Order = N` at the end, where N is the invoice id you want to add.